# Best way resize photo gallery for preview

Tags: objective-c, ios

My app has more then 1000 photos and 50 galleries. It looks like as iphone Photos app. In preview list of gallery I have problem with performance. 
In profile I saw what [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect] take 96% of time. 
What is the best way to fix this issue?

Duplicate with small size of images I did.
Perhaps there is another solution?

Comment: Do the photos change, or is it the same 1000 photos for every user?

Comment: Yes, 1000 photos for every user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to create thumbnail images for every Image File and save them as thumb_orginalimagefilename.png.

Comment: I have tree types of galleries. In each type i use different size(65x65, 73x73, 280x320). Solution with thumbnail images is good, but I need dublicate image three times. I thought what exist faster solution to resize image than drawInRect.

Comment: I would use 65x65 for 65x65 and 73x73. Because nobody see the difference. And for the 280x320 you can load first the 65x65 and replace it if the big image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can batch edit images in many desktop publishing programs.

[Photoshop](http://www.digital-photography-school.com/how-to-batch-resize-in-photoshop) or [Fireworks](http://digital-photography-school.com/forum/tutorials/95219-how-run-batch-process-fireworks-resize-whole-folder-images.html).  In Picasa you can just multi-select a ton of images, like an entire folder and then [Export to File](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13821) and choose the output size

Answer (score 0):

Create three large images that contain all of the thumbs in each gallery and load them in one UIScrollView with semi-transparent UIImageButtons over the locations where the thumbs appear in the image.

This could prove faster, since you only load one image per gallery, but you would have to try it to find out.  I have done this before as it helped to reduce the size of my app.